# Animating a countdown timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My project currently features quizzes, which have a countdown timer using Javascript. This time then resets to 7 seconds after it has counted down fully or a the user selects a multiple-choice answer.

That function is working, but it just shows how much time is left, in text. I want to make a "bar" (think: column) that counts down (so, if a quiz gives you 7 seconds, the bar reduces 1/7th each time). jQuery and Javascript seem to be the easiest way to do this, so I added:

```
var height = 50;
var timePassed = 0;
var totalSeconds = 7;

var reduceHeight = function(elem, totalSeconds){
timePassed++;
height = 100 - (100/totalSeconds * timePassed);
elem.css({height: height + "%"});
if(height > 0){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
  reduceHeight(elem, totalSeconds)
  }, 1000)
  }
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  var inner = $('#inner');
  reduceHeight(inner, 20);
  });
```

The bar now appears and does count down, but it is not completing reduceHeight at the correct rate.

Since I am defining the totalSeconds variable, it seems like it should since height is being set at 100/totalSeconds * timePassed. To reiterate, as the timer will run for 7 seconds, I would want it to become 1/7th smaller in each passing second.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: setTimeout will not guarantee that its turn will come in 1 second, it will simply be available for execution in 1 second. Use the date time logic rather than a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your height calculation logic is incorrect

it should be

```
height = 100 - ( ( timePassed/totalSeconds ) * 100 );
```

since for example `totalSeconds` is 20 and `timePassed` is 10
then you height should be 50,

```
height = 100 - ( ( 10/20 ) * 100 ) = 50;
```

Which means that you need to

- get the ratio of `timePassed` with `totalSeconds`
- and then get the percentage out of that ratio
- so that you can reduce that percentage value from `100`